# Calculating Time difference between two Time class of different date

Tags: java, datetime

Everyone

This question is common and I searched the forum but none of the solution seems to be working.

My database(MySql) Framework(Hibernate) return me a Time Object and I want to get the difference in time between the Time Object and the System current time.

This is my code:

```
Time time=a.getTime();
System.out.println(time);
Time currentTime=new Time((new Date()).getTime());
System.out.println(currentTime);
long diff=time.getTime()-currentTime.getTime();
System.out.println(diff);
executor.schedule(caller,diff,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Output:

```
03:51:46
03:25:12
-1372548806938
```

Expected Output

```
03:51:46
03:25:12
1594000
```

I guess this is because the date in which time object created are different.
How can I get the expected output.

Note:As I have already constructed the database I dont want to change the return type of Object a i.e Object a will return Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use following code you can see expected out put received

```
    Time time=Time.valueOf("03:51:46");
    System.out.println(time);
    Time currentTime=Time.valueOf("03:25:12");
    System.out.println(currentTime);
    long diff=time.getTime()-currentTime.getTime();
    System.out.println(diff);
```

So format your object as follows

```
    System.out.println(time);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date preTime=df.parse(df.format(time));
    Date sysTime = df.parse(df.format(new Date()));
    System.out.println(sysTime);
    long diff=preTime.getTime()-sysTime.getTime();
    System.out.println(diff);
```